Fluent NHibernate multiple tables with shared data models
I work with a database with several practically identical tables. For illustrative purposes they look like this:
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Title) VALUE (1, 'foo')
INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Title) VALUE (2, 'bar')

CREATE TABLE DifferentTable (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO DifferentTable (Id, Title) VALUE (1, 'foobar')

I though I'd create one datamodel that could be shared between these tables:
public class GenericTable
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}

public class GenericTableMap : ClassMap<GenericTable>
{
    public GenericTableMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
    }
}

And then the plan was to do the following manual lookups:
List<GenericTable> result = MyNHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
    .AddEntity(typeof(GenericTable))
    .List<GenericTable>()
    .ToList();

List<GenericTable> differentResult = MyNHibernateSession.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM DifferentTable")
    .AddEntity(typeof(GenericTable))
    .List<GenericTable>()
    .ToList();

The problem I'm facing is that result and differentResult both contain entries from MyTable!
result          == [ { 1, "foo" }, { 2, "bar" } ]
differentResult == [ { 1, "foo" } ]

I would expect differentResult to contain "foobar".
I've tried using different sessions, but that produced the same result.
If I create two separate models and mapping then it works as expected, but it defeats the purpose of a generic data model.
What am I missing here?

Can cheat and use inheritance: class GenericTable2 : GenericTable, then apply GenericTable2's own mapping.

Have you enabled logging at a sufficiently low level? This will often reveal insights into why NH is doing what it's doing.

@DavidOsborne I have enabled enough logging to see the SQL being generated, which matches the code, and matches what is actually run on the SQL server. What other logging could I turn on, and what should I look for?

This is old but shows how to enable additional logging. https://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.  Look at the NHibernate logger as well as the NHibernate.SQL one. IIRC, this will tell you more about what's going on.
